# R shiny: renderTable reset input$tableid_rows_selected value

Tags: r, shiny

**Background :** I'm creating a simple table using the following code:

```
output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({
              datatable(data_frame_object, selection='single')
              })
```

Note that `selection='single'` makes it so that only one row is shown as selected at a time. 
I track the row that is selected by the user by using the following code:

```
index=input$mytable_rows_selected
```

**Problem :**  The problem I am having is that I want to reset the value of `index=input$mytable_rows_selected` every time a new row is selected. 
Currently, if user selects row 1, the index will have value [1]. If user then selects row 2, then index will have value of [1, 2]. However, I just want index to have value of [2].

**Attempted solution:**  My workaround has been to use index[length(index)] to get the row that was last selected,but this is not suitable for my purposes.

**Working example using iris data:**

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable(iris[,c(1,4,5)],selection='single')
  }, 
  options = list(lengthMenu = c(5, 30, 50), pageLength = 10, orderClasses=TRUE)
  ) 

  output$info = DT::renderDataTable({

    index=input$mytable_rows_selected

    if (length(index)){
      index2=index[length(index)]
    }
    else{
      index2=index
    }
    iris[index2,c(1,4)]
  }, 
  options = list(pageLength = 5, orderClasses=TRUE, searching=FALSE)
  )

}

ui <- fluidPage(

  fluidRow(
    column(4,dataTableOutput('mytable')),

    column(6,offset=1,
           tabsetPanel(type="tabs", 
                       tabPanel("hi",dataTableOutput('info')))
    )   
  )
)
```

Comment: For me `input$mytable_rows_selected` takes the last value as intended. What version of a `DT` package are you using? Maybe an update will solve this.

Comment: For my DT version(0.1) i can use `input$mytable_row_last_clicked`

Comment: My DT version is (0.1) as well. Thanks Batanichek, that seems to work mostly, except that I would like to to  be set to NULL again if I de-select a row. I guess I'll have to do this manuallly?

Comment: Hmm.. you can try to combine `rows_selected` and `row_last_cliked` like     `index=input$mytable_row_last_clicked
    index2=input$mytable_rows_selected

if( !is.null(index)){
  if(!index %in% index2){
    iris[0,c(1,4)]
  }else{iris[index,c(1,4)]}
  }else{iris[0,c(1,4)]}`

Comment: Thanks that's a good idea

Comment: you can use `datatableProxy` to de-select rows programmatically

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable(iris[,c(1,4,5)],selection='single')
  }, 
  options = list(lengthMenu = c(5, 30, 50), pageLength = 10, orderClasses=TRUE)
  ) 

  selected.rows <- reactiveValues(index = NULL)

  observe({
      selected.rows$index <- input$mytable_rows_selected
  })

  output$info = DT::renderDataTable({

    index=selected.rows$index

    if (length(index)){
      index2=index[length(index)]
    }
    else{
      index2=index
    }
    iris[index2,c(1,4)]
  }, 
  options = list(pageLength = 5, orderClasses=TRUE, searching=FALSE)
  )

}

ui <- fluidPage(

  fluidRow(
    column(4,dataTableOutput('mytable')),

    column(6,offset=1,
           tabsetPanel(type="tabs", 
                       tabPanel("hi",dataTableOutput('info')))
    )   
  )
)
```